# how to solve error The directory name is invalid in cmd

Tags: python

how to solve error The directory name is invalid in cmd while operating with pipenv

here is the code-

```
C:\Users\Admin>cd C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\sound in python\sound.py
The directory name is invalid
```

I've tried  putting this directory into path of environment variable but it didn't worked what to do please explain in simple language

Comment: cd is to enter a directory. not a file. you're using it wrong. also you need to wrap the directory name with apostrophes cd "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\sound in python". because you have whitespaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change directory to a *file* while you should be changing to a *folder*.

So you should try this:

```
cd C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProject\sound in python
```